# Подстроить ширину блока по тексту

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5

Есть одна задача, не могу решить
У нас есть блок у которого фиксированная высота. Например 280px. В этом блоке у нас есть простой текст, но его может быть как пару слов так и пару абзацев. И вот нужно весь текст поместить в этот блок (не обрезая). А в случае если текста будет много, то блок нужно не увеличить по высоте, а увеличить по ширине, чтобы текст все равно влез. То есть блок в любом случае должен остаться 280px в высоту, а в ширину должен растягиваться[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Приведу пример как картинку, заранее всем спасибо

Comment: Фиксированная должна быть высота
На картинке первый прямоугольник имеет высоту 280 и второй 280, а ширина у них 300 и 450 соответственно

Т.е при большом кол-ве текста я должен оставлять высоту в 280 и растягивать блок по ширине

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
max-height: 280px;
min-width: 300px;
max-width: 100%;
```

Думаю объяснять не нужно.

Comment: Ситуация вот такая, нужно чтобы текст на зеленом растянулся на 100%, а не вылезал за пределы снизу
https://jsfiddle.net/Lctq4szr/

Comment: @SeregaPokofjev
overflow: auto; - появится полоса прокрутки.
overflow: hidden; - текст что вылазит за рамки не будет видет.

Comment: Так работать не будет. Нужно писать скрипт

Comment: Да, я понимаю что только css здесь не обойтись, если не сложно подскажите как это реализовать на jquery